# Understanding “dem Kind, das für den Vater fleht”

Tags: meaning-in-context, verb-usage

The question is on *für* in the third stanza of [Ave Maria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ave_Maria_%28Schubert%29).

> Ave Maria! Reine Magd!
>   Der Erde und der Luft Dämonen,
>   Von deines Auges Huld verjagt,
>   Sie können hier nicht bei uns wohnen,
>   Wir woll’n uns still dem Schicksal beugen,
>   Da uns dein heil’ger Trost anweht;
>   Der Jungfrau wolle hold dich neigen,
>   Dem Kind, das **für** den Vater fleht.
>   Ave Maria!

**QUESTION**

Is the child praying for his or her (human) father, and not to his or her (Heavenly) Father?

**BACKGROUND**

The [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ave_Maria_%28Schubert%29) will give you the full poem.  There was no previous mention of any father to the child.  I presume *das Kind* is the praying Jungfrau (not to be confused with Jungfrau Maria).

Here’s a bit more on what’s motivating the question.  Analogizing from English *pray for* I may expect German *für X flehen* could have for X (a) a beneficiary (“pray for our boys in the trenches”) or (b) a desired outcome (“pray for peace”), but not (c) the deity to be addressed (such as the Heavenly Father).  But in the poem *den Vater* rather comes out of nowhere at the very end and seems to—shall we say—injure the poem.  Till then, it was about the world being an inhospitable crack in the rock where we needed the rose scent from above, etc.; but suddenly our praying maiden has some specific business about her dad, who—I don’t know—embezzled or got the plague?  If (c) were available in German, the poem could end as it started:  in the abstract.

Comment: I’m going to change _his_ in the question into _his or her_. Context clearly shows the speaker is female, so _his_ is wrong; but I’ll leave both options since the OP apparently isn’t sure of this.

Comment: [Please do not answer questions in comments](http://german.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the content of the text, not the language in which it is written.

Comment: Did you read in the Wikipedia article that this text is a translation from English? The corresponding English phrase is _for a father hear a child_.

Comment: @chirlu Yes, that "father" is surely nobody's Heavenly Father.  The ending of the English original has up to four people praying or being prayed for, and so may suggest "a whole lot of praying going on in the world" and not so badly take the poem from the abstract to the concrete.

Comment: The *child* theme comes at the end of every stanza, I do not see it coming out of the blue.

Comment: I’ve just answered the core language question, which is all that is in the scope of this site. I’d like to point out, however, that already the first and second stanzas indicate the girl is not alone: She repeatedly uses _we_ for those who are “banish'd, outcast and reviled”, referring to herself, her father and possibly others. Also note that this poem is part of a larger context, summarized by Wikipedia thus: _Ellen Douglas … has gone with her exiled father to stay in the Goblin’s cave as he has declined to join their previous host … in rebellion against King James._

Comment: @chirlu Indeed I had not read about the wider context when I posted the question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only possible interpretation is that the pleading happens in the interest of the *Vater*, or possibly in his place (if he would, but can’t do the pleading himself for some reason). This is the general scope of the preposition *für*.

Historically, according to the [DWB entry for *flehen*](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?bookref=3,1749,49), accusative or dative could be used to indicate the person whom the pleading is directed at (*jemanden flehen*, *jemandem flehen*). This is no longer the case; today, the transitive verb *anflehen* would be preferred for this (*jemanden anflehen*), or at the most *flehen* could be used with the preposition *zu* (*zu jemandem flehen*).

Regarding the desired result of the pleading, this could in former times be expressed in accusative (*Gnade flehen*), but again, this usage has disappeared in modern language. Either the preposition *um* – but never *für* – would be used (*um Gnade flehen*), or again a transitive prefix verb, *erflehen* (*Gnade erflehen*).